# Does vim-easymotion only work in neovim?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, version, plugin, init

I was wondering if the `easymotion-overwin` was compatible with vim, or does it only works in neovim?

I have my `.vimrc`'s keymaps setup like this for `easy-motion`

```
"----- Easy-Motion -----
map <leader> <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)
map <leader>f <Plug>(easymotion-bd-w)
nmap <leader>f <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-w)
```

The problem is that the `easymotion-overwin` is not working in vim.

However, I have the exact same configuration for neovim, and it works just fine.
I even tried source my `init.vim` file inside of my `.vimrc` and it still doesn't work...

For reference, [`easymotion`](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion/blob/master/doc/easymotion.txt) is a plugin that allows to jump to words quickly, and the way `easymotion-overwin` works, is that it allow to jump to words, in  multiple windows. In neovim, (where it works), here is what it looks like:

[image]

However, when i try to do the same in vim, it looks the same, but if i try to click one of the `{char}` options to jump to a word, it does not work, and goes to a random word instead...

**After some research, the problem seem to come from the plugin and MacOSX. On this [github](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion/issues/372) issues page, the recommended solution is to `brew install macvim`, and it will fix the problem.**

**If anyone finds a solution to this, please let me know**

Comment: Thanks. Welcome to Vi&Vim SE.

Comment: I don't see in their doc any mention of this feature (or any feature) working only with neovim, since that looks like a bug (assuming you took the time to test with a clean vimrc and only this plugin) I think [their issue tracker](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion/issues) is the best place to ask this question.

Comment: @statox, it seems that other people are having problems with this. I tried just installing macvim, and it started working... The problem must come from the plugin, so all i can do is wait.

Comment: @needle So that future reader with the same problem know what you just found out could you answer your question, maybe with a link to the relevant Github issue?